# Firebase Authentication only works after closing and reopening app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm building an Android app that queries a Firebase Cloud Firestore database, and for doing this, the user must be authenticated because of this rule:

```
match /{document=**} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
```

However, after authenticating with Google inside of the app, a query is executed and fails giving the insufficient permissions message:

```
D/: Query failed: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Here's the code:

```
    private fun firebaseAuthenticateGoogle(account: GoogleSignInAccount?) {
    try {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account?.idToken, null)

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener { i ->
            val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(mAuth.app)
            firestore.collection("units").document("1").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Query was successful")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Query failed: " + e.message)
                }
        }
    }
```

If I close the app and reopen it, it works fine, as if the user were only authenticated after closing the app. However, if I check if `mAuth.currentuser == null` it returns false, so the user should be authenticated right after clicking the Sign In button...

Comment: Have you tried the following rule `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;`?

Comment: I did, got the same problem...

Comment: This seems unexpected: inside the completion listener you should be able to access documents in the database. Are you sure it is *this* specific code raising the error? I'm specifically interested in how this code is effected on a restart.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I actually found the problem: somehow, getting the Firestore instance using `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(mAuth.app)` raised the error. I changed it to `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance())` and now it works perfectly (even though it's theoretically the same instance of `FirebaseApp` beign used, given that `mAuth` (FirebaseAuth) also uses the default FirebaseApp instance.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure how it would make a difference, but good to hear that you found the problem and were able to solve it. 